# send blank SMS with SmsManager.sendTextMessage method in android

Tags: android, sms, illegalargumentexception, smsmanager

I created an android app and one of its functions is to send SMS, when I try to send blank SMS it throws an exception.

Here is the code:

```
SmsManager sm=SmsManager.getDefault();
sm.sendTextMessage("9999", null, messageBody,sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

messageBody maybe empty string and maybe it is a string, previous method throws IllegalArgumentException when messageBody is empty string!

what can I do to send blank SMS?

Comment: try to send space instead of NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

This method:

Throws

```
IllegalArgumentException    if destinationAddress or text are empty
```

Comment: You can't send a blank sms.

Comment: There is an app in the store called BlankSMS that sends blank SMS somehow... works great for me.